# Stored procedure - looping through results and store them in a temporary table

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

My issue I'm having is that Mysql workbench is reporting a SQL Syntax Error near '`DELARE tempOrder_id int;`' with declare underlined in red although I cant seem to see an error, also haven’t been able to test this yet either so if you spot any other errors or more efficient ways to run this please say. it should be easy to under stand I'm grabbing the id from a query then running a new query with that id and storing it in a table so that I can return it

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `DLP_orders ` ()
BEGIN
    Create temporary table if not exists MyReturnTable
        (id int, order_id int, total_tickets int, product_id int, product_name varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=MEMORY;

    DECLARE tempOrder_id int;
    DECLARE order_Cursor;

    SELECT o.id FROM orders as o
        INNER JOIN orders_items as oi
            ON o.id = oi.order_id
        INNER JOIN contracts as c
            ON c.id = oi.contract_id
    WHERE (o.created BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-02 23:59:59' OR o.updated BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-02 23:59:59') AND (c.supplier_id = 95 || c.supplier_id = 255);

    OPEN order_Cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM order_Cursor INTO @tempOrder_id;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO MyReturnTable (order_id, total_tickets,  product_id, product_name)
                SELECT o.id, oi.total_tickets, p.id, p.name FROM orders as o
                    INNER JOIN orders_items as oi
                        ON o.id = oi.order_id
                    INNER JOIN products as p
                        ON p.id = oi.product_id
                    INNER JOIN contracts as c
                        ON c.id = oi.contract_id
                WHERE o.id = @tempOrder_id;

            FETCH NEXT FROM order_Cursor INTO @tempOrder_id;
        END;

    CLOSE order_Cursor;
    DEALLOCATE order_Cursor;

    SELECT * FROM MyReturnTable;
END$$
```

Comment: The syntax error isn't immediately popping out to me... but what is popping out is that there's absolutely no reason to use a cursor for this... it can be accomplished with joins and subqueries and will be much less complex.

Comment: can you explain the, issue i had with just joins is that the where supplier_id clause also filtered out results that matched by order id which isnt what i want, as order_id isn't unique

Comment: im not and expert MYSQL programmer but i think ur missing things on your code. for example you dont actualy define any cursor. I used [this example](http://www.kbedell.com/2009/03/02/a-simple-example-of-a-mysql-stored-procedure-that-uses-a-cursor/) when i whant to make a stored procedure.

Comment: i figured out the first error it was because DECLARE statements have to go first, ill post annswer if i solve some of these other errors or update Q if i cant solve them

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution after a bit of tweaking

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `DLP_orders` ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE tempOrder_id int;
    DECLARE order_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT o.id FROM orders as o
        INNER JOIN orders_items as oi
            ON o.id = oi.order_id
        INNER JOIN contracts as c
            ON c.id = oi.contract_id
    WHERE (o.created BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-02 23:59:59' OR o.updated BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-02 23:59:59') AND (c.supplier_id = 95 || c.supplier_id = 255);

    OPEN order_Cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM order_Cursor INTO tempOrder_id;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 DO
            INSERT INTO MyReturnTable (order_id, total_tickets,  product_id, product_name)
                SELECT o.id, oi.total_tickets, p.id, p.name FROM orders as o
                    INNER JOIN orders_items as oi
                        ON o.id = oi.order_id
                    INNER JOIN products as p
                        ON p.id = oi.product_id
                    INNER JOIN contracts as c
                        ON c.id = oi.contract_id
                WHERE o.id = @tempOrder_id;

            FETCH NEXT FROM order_Cursor INTO tempOrder_id;
    END WHILE;

    CLOSE order_Cursor;

    SELECT * FROM MyReturnTable;
END
```